# Unable to resolve service for type interface while attempting to activate controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, repository-pattern

I have this Solution which Contains three Projects.

1. **BookStoreAPI**
2. **BookStore.Data**
3. **BookStoreWebUI**

- 1 is my API in .net core which contains BooksController.
- 2 is my class library project which contains three folders (Interfaces,Model,Repository).
- 3 is my web UI in ASP.Net for consuming this API.

[image: My Solution and inside three projects]

[image]

**Description**
I have created this API in .NET core and it works fine, but the occurred when I build UI for it and wanted to consume it in the ASP .NET MVC. When I run the app it loads my index page which loads all the data from database, but when I click on any button on index page like 'addbook', 'updatebook', 'getbookbyid' then it gives me this error

**Error Message**

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'BookStore.Data.Interfaces.IBookRepository' while attempting to activate 'BookStoreAPI.Controllers.BooksController'.

[image: Error Image]

**Startup.cs in the BookStoreAPI**

```
namespace BookStoreAPI{

public class Startup
{
    readonly string constr;

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).CreateLogger();
        Configuration = configuration;
        constr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("myconnection");

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IBookRepository,BookRepository>();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "BookStoreAPI", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "BookStoreAPI v1"));
        }
        loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

}

**Startup.cs in the BookStoreWebUI**

```
namespace BookStoreWebUI{

public class Startup{

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

}

**BooksController.cs in the BookStoreAPI**

```
namespace BookStoreAPI.Controllers{

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class BooksController : ControllerBase
{
    private IBookRepository bookRepository { get; }
    public BooksController(IBookRepository repo)
    {
        bookRepository = repo;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooks()
    {
        return bookRepository.GetAllBooks().ToList();
    }
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public Book GetBookById(int id)
    {
        return bookRepository.GetBook(id);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public Book AddBook([FromBody] Book book)
    {
        return bookRepository.AddBook(book);
    }
    [HttpPut]
    public Book UpdateBook([FromForm] Book book)
    {
        return bookRepository.UpdateBook(book);
    }
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void DeleteBook(int id)
    {
        bookRepository.Delete(id);
    }

}
```

}

**BooksController.cs in the BookStoreWebUI**

```
namespace BookStoreWebUI.Controllers{

public class BooksController : Controller
{       
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
        using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpclient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44374/api/Books"))
            {
                var apiresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Book>>(apiresponse);
            }
        }
        return View(books);
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult GetBooks()
    {
        return View();

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBooks(int id)
    {

        Book book = new Book();
        using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpclient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44374/api/Books/"+id))
            {
                var apiresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                book = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Book>(apiresponse);
            }
        }
        return View(book);

    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult AddBook()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddBook(Book book)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
            {
                StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(book), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                using (var response = await httpclient.PostAsync("https://localhost:44374/api/Books/" , content))
                {
                    var apiresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    book = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Book>(apiresponse);
                }
            }
            return View(book);
        }
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateBook(int id)
    {
        Book book = new Book();
        using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpclient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44374/api/Books/" + id))
            {
                var apiresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                book = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Book>(apiresponse);
            }
        }
        return View(book);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateBook(Book book)
    {
        Book recievedbook = new Book();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                content.Add(new StringContent(book.Id.ToString()),"Id");
                content.Add(new StringContent(book.Title), "Title");
                content.Add(new StringContent(book.Author), "Author");
                content.Add(new StringContent(book.PublicationYear.ToString()), "PublicationYear");
                content.Add(new StringContent(book.IsAvailable.ToString()), "IsAvailable");
                content.Add(new StringContent(book.CallNumber), "CallNumber");

                using (var response = await httpclient.PutAsync("https://localhost:44374/api/Books/" ,content))
                {
                    var apiresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    ViewBag.Result = "Success";
                    recievedbook = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Book>(apiresponse);
                }
            }
        }
        return View(recievedbook);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteBook(int id)
    {
        using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response =  await httpclient.DeleteAsync("https://localhost:44374/api/Books/"))
            {
                string apiresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

}

**Books Repository in BooksStore.Data.Repository**

namespace BookStore.Data.Repositories{

```
public class BookRepository : IBookRepository{

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
    public string constr;
    private readonly ILogger<BookRepository> _logger;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = null;
    SqlDataReader sdr = null;

    public BookRepository(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<BookRepository> logger)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        constr = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:myconnection"];
    }

    public IEnumerable<Book> GetAllBooks()
    {
        List<Book> list = new List<Book>();
        using (con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("getallbooks", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchvalue", null);
                sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(new Book
                    {
                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Id"]),
                        Title = Convert.ToString(sdr["Title"]),
                        Author = Convert.ToString(sdr["Author"]),
                        PublicationYear = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["PublicationYear"]),
                        IsAvailable = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["IsAvailable"]),
                        CallNumber = Convert.ToString(sdr["CallNumber"])

                    });
                }
                sdr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex,"Error at GetAllBooks() : ");
                list = null;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public Book GetBook(int id)
    {
        Book book = new Book();
        using (con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("getallbooks", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchvalue", id);
                sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    book = new Book
                    {
                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Id"]),
                        Title = Convert.ToString(sdr["Title"]),
                        Author = Convert.ToString(sdr["Author"]),
                        PublicationYear = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["PublicationYear"]),
                        IsAvailable = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["IsAvailable"]),
                        CallNumber = Convert.ToString(sdr["CallNumber"])
                    };
                }
                sdr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error at GetBookbyid() : ");
                book = null;
            }
        }
        return book;
    }

   

    public Book AddBook(Book book)
    {
        using (con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("addbook", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", book.Title);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", book.Author);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PublicationYear", book.PublicationYear);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsAvailable", book.IsAvailable);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallNumber", book.CallNumber);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error at AddBook() : ");
                book = null;
            }
        }
        return book;
    }

    public Book UpdateBook(Book book)
    {
        using (con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("addbook", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", book.Id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", book.Title);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", book.Author);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PublicationYear", book.PublicationYear);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsAvailable", book.IsAvailable);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallNumber", book.CallNumber);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error at AddBook() : ");
                book = null;
            }
        }
        return book;
    }
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        using (con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("deletebook", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error at AddBook() : ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**appsetting.json in the BookStoreAPI**

```
{
```

"ConnectionStrings": {

```
"myconnection": "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=BooksDB;Integrated Security=True"
```

},

"Serilog": {

```
"MinimumLevel": "Error",

"WriteTo": [
  {

    "Name": "RollingFile",

    "Args": {

      "pathFormat": "C:\\Temp\\log-{Date}.txt",

      "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",

      "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error"
    }
  }
],

"Properties": {
  "Application": "Common feature in WebApi demo"
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with routing.
I had to add this line in the BooksController in the WebUI Project.

> ```
> [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
> ```

and the issue was resolved.
Basically the problem was that when i would run the app it would load the index page and get all data from database and show it in the table, but when i click any button on that index page it would not go and gives me this error and it would go to api. But the issue is solved now